# ThinkPad x220 / 12.04 / Fingerprint reader not working after upgrade

Tags: thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my ThinkPad X220 and I'm happy with it.

After following a certain guide to enable the use of the fingerprint reader, everything worked fine and I was asked to my fingerprint in order to log-in and in order to use sudo.

Normal password was a fallback when fingerprint matching failed.

Today something happened: I upgraded my system and I'm not asked for my fingerprint anymore.

How can I restore working behaviour ?

Comment: Could you add the link of the guide you followed to enable the fingerprint reader?

Answer (score 0):

**Try these steps once**

- open a terminal by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and execute these commands in series.

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
  ```

  wait for sometime till this command executes completely. Then execute rest:

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure $(dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep "^xserver" | tr '\n' ' ')
  sudo update-initramfs -u
  sudo update-grub
  ```
- then restart your computer and see what happens.

Reply if something goes wrong, or for further assitance.

Comment: Please explain, what those commands will do.

Comment: There is an link of top-right of your page named [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask), click on that and you are ready to ask any question you want.. Hope you would get a lot of answers also..

Comment: @SnoopyStinson: actually when you upgraded your `kernel` you may have to re-configure already installed packages. doing this will allow them to identified by the latest `Kernel`. That is why some time it is recommended to un-install some packages which show some dependencies problem, before `Upgrading to a newer Kernel`.

Comment: You misunderstood - to make an answer good it should explain the steps, not just perform some "magic".

Comment: ha ha ha ;) Cool.. you would have noticed that I've mentioned in short in my previous comment. I was expecting from the questioner that he would ask something..

Comment: Actually i was waiting for the command to work in order to ask for clarification.
Every time i run that command some packages pop around saying they are not installed.

Comment: In which command you get the errors? Can you describe that one, and also what errors you are getting?